# difference between typeof "andrei" and typeof "andrei".valueOf()

Tags: javascript, string

1. I logged both and they've returned the same result , but there must be a
   slight difference.

Comment: Why would you expect a difference?  If you are confused about something...explain why

Comment: if((typeof name !="undefined") &&
 (typeof name.valueOf()=="string") &&
 (name.length>0)) in this one i deleted valueOf() and the result was the same and i was courious about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference, unless someone's done something silly to the JavaScript environment.

`"andrei"` is a string primitive, thus `typeof "andrei"` is `"string"`. If you do `"andrei".valueOf()`, you're coercing a string primitive into a `String` object (in theory*) because you're accessing a property on it (`valueOf`), and then asking that object for its primitive value — which is a primitive string, thus `typeof "andrei".valueOf()` is `"string"`.

Of course, you could replace `String.prototype.valueOf` with something other than the default which broke tne `String.prototype.valueOf` contract by returning, say, a number or object. But that's out in bizarre-land.

---

* "in theory" - JavaScript engines are free to optimize operations provided the optimization doesn't make things behave in a way that isn't according to spec. So a JavaScript engine could optimize away calling `.valueOf()` on a string primitive provided `String.prototype.valueOf` is still the same as its default value (which the engine can easily be aware of), since the result is just the same as the primitive. I don't know whether they *do*, but they could.

---

Re your comment on the question:

> ```
>  if((typeof name !="undefined") && (typeof name.valueOf()=="string") && (name.length>0))
> ```
>
> in this one i `deleted valueOf()` and the result was the same and i was courious about that.

Ah! That's a different thing, for two reasons:

1. `name` may not be a string. Lots of things have `length` properties — strings, functions, basic arrays, typed arrays, DOM collections, any number of script-defined objects...
2. `name` may be a `String` *object* (although it's unlikely, people don't normally use `String` objects unless writing extension methods for `String.prototype`, in which case `this` refers to a `String` object).

So removing that `typeof name.valueOf()=="string"` part would change the condition. Re the `.valueOf()` part: The author of that code is either a bit paranoid or there's a reason to expect that `name` may be a `String` object (and so its type would be `"object"`, not `"string"`). Using `valueOf` ensures that he/she is checking the primitive instead.

Surprisingly, they weren't paranoid enough (at least, without context), since `null` would cause an exception in that code.

The `()` around each condition are also completely unnecessary.

Handling `null` as well looks like this:

```
if (name != null && typeof name.valueOf() == "string" && name.length > 0)
```

Comment: thanks,really good explanation, i like asking questions about stuff in general , any idea why i got -3 score on my question ? i hope it was not because i was lazy or something else. I am kind of new to this sort of things and i enjoy learning but i dont want to be viewed badly on this comunitty

Comment: The next time, try learning the [documentation for the interested method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/valueOf) first

Comment: @AndreiSerban: I don't know. But taking the time to present your question clearly and completely always helps. That includes things like not using a numbered list when there's no point to it, perhaps saying *why* you think there must be a difference, talking about what you understand `valueOf` does (or at least making sure it's clear you have looked it up), etc. Happy coding,

Comment: @AndreiSerban: I saw your comment on the question and updated the answer to address it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm trying to do the examples in the javascript cookbook . i first take them in their original state but then i like to tinker with them . So far i think some examples are challenging but overall the book is great and makes me feel very motivated.

Answer (score 0):

There are no actual differences between `"string".valueOf()` returning value and `"string"` in JavaScript because `String.prototype.valueOf()` method returns the string-primitive object itself (as and `String.prototype.toString()` does).

```
typeof "string" === typeof "string".valueOf() //true
```

The only performance difference between using `(String).valueOf()` and `(String)` (for ex., due to comparsion) is that calling simple `(String)` is faster (of course, saying that `(String)` - is a prototype-unmodified object instance of `String` class).